# Vue.js - control the router from inside a mutation in Vuex Store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vue-router

I have the following problem:

This is one of my mutations:

```
tryAutoLogin(state) {
  console.log("Trying auto login...");
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
  if (!token) {
    return;
  }
  const expirationDate = window.localStorage.getItem("token_exp");
  const now = new Date();
  if (now >= expirationDate) {
    return;
  }
  state.userData.loggedIn = true;
  state.userData.username = token.identity;
  // desired: this.$router.push("/dashboard") => results in undefined
}
```

Currently I commit this mutation inside my component in the created phase of the component:

```
  created() {
    this.$store.commit("tryAutoLogin");
    this.$router.push("/dashboard");
  }
```

This is not a great way to do it, since I would have to output a value, store it in a variable and use if/else to this `this.$router.push("/dashboard")`.

How can I solve this in an elegant way? Favorable inside the mutation like in the `// desired` comment. Is there a way to access the router inside the Vuex store?

Comment: try use vue-router `guards`

Comment: I'd say it is not a good practice to do what you're trying to do in the mutation there are navigation guards you can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the vue component instance to the mutation like:

```
 this.$store.commit("tryAutoLogin",this);
```

in mutation add it as parameter `vm` then use it as `vm.$router.push("/dashboard")`  :

```
tryAutoLogin(state,vm) {
  console.log("Trying auto login...");
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
  if (!token) {
    return;
  }
  const expirationDate = window.localStorage.getItem("token_exp");
  const now = new Date();
  if (now >= expirationDate) {
    return;
  }
  state.userData.loggedIn = true;
  state.userData.username = token.identity;
  vm.$router.push("/dashboard") 
}
```

Comment: you should to use vue-router `guards` like a middleware before to join to some route, there you can apply the corresponding logic.
also inside your component you can use the `beforeRouteEnter` guard as a secondary option